# Class library allow use unassigned structures

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have my structure:

```
public struct MyType
{
    private string value;

    // Methods
    // ... (ToString overrided too)
}
```

If I put the structure in Program.cs or another File.cs, and I create a variable as `MyType` (my structure) and I try to use it, the result is an obvious error:

> CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable

Example:

```
MyType a; 
Console.WriteLine(a); // Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'a'

MyType b = new MyType(); 
Console.WriteLine(b); // Prints the default value (an empty string)
```

The problem is when I put the structure in a class library (either in another project, or from a NuGet package) and I use it from Program.cs:

```
MyType a;
Console.WriteLine(a); // No error: prints an empty string
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the output in the second scenario?

Comment: Corrected my answer (totally missed the Class Library part... sorry)!

Comment: @DmitryK. An empty string. Added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is by design. See this issue on GitHub:

['error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable' is not produced for structs with a private reference type field from a different assembly](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1722)

This issue has been closed and labeled as "Resolution-By Design".

In that issue, [gafter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1722#issuecomment-88528394) has this to say:

> This was a very painful but intentional decision. This duplicates the (buggy) behavior of the previous compiler. I strongly recommend you add the compiler flag `/features:strict` to get the correct, specification-required (but not backward-compatible) behavior.

Comment: But what relation exists between the strict mode (must cast all variables) and don't initialize a structure?

Comment: @Joe No idea. From the same comment in the GitHub issue, gafter says "This is not currently in the docs" and it still appears that it is not documented.

Answer (score -1):

When you call `Console.WriteLine` from a class library, unless the project you are running supports a console (command prompt), it will do nothing. It's the same for `Debug.WriteLine` in environment that doesn't support debugging.

Comment: This isn't the problem. Using `a.ToString()` has the same problem - the error is there when the type is defined locally, but not there when the type is defined in another assembly.